# raise statement on a conditional expression

Tags: python, exception, conditional-statements, raise

How do I elegantly implement the ["Samurai principle"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SamuraiPrinciple) (*return victorious, or not at all*) on my functions?

```
return <value> if <bool> else raise <exception>
```

Comment: What is that *Samurai* here? What do you think about adding some details?

Comment: the Samurai Principle - Return victorious, or not at all. If a function fulfills its responsibilities, return the appropiate result object, and if it doesn't then throw an Exception.

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe some link would be good, such as [Samurai Principle](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SamuraiPrinciple)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Inline/ternary `if` is an expression, not a statement. Your attempt means "if bool, return value, else return the result of `raise expression`" - which is nonsense of course, because `raise exception` is itself a statement not an expression.

There's no way to do this inline, and you shouldn't want to. Do it explicitly:

```
if not bool:
    raise MyException
return value
```

Comment: I think the question can actually be translated to: is there a way to raise an exception as an expression instead as a statement? To which the answer is yes, as @glglgl suggested.

Answer (score 34):

If you absolutely want to `raise` in an expression, you could do

```
def raiser(ex): raise ex

return <value> if <bool> else raiser(<exception>)
```

This "tries" to return the return value of `raiser()`, which would be `None`, if there was no unconditional `raise` in the function.

Comment: I find this handy for the short-hand ternary when configuring a settings file that relies on environment variables. This way I can still have clean dict rows down the file, but also give helpful and more specific error messages when a specific setting is simply missing. Ex: `{'f': os.environ.get('FOO') or raise_foobar(), ...}`

Answer (score 2):

I like to do it with assertions, so you emphasize that that member must to be, like a contract.

```
>>> def foo(self):
...     assert self.value, "Not Found"
...     return self.value
```

Comment: In such way you wouldn't raise a specific execption, would you?

Comment: I've also noticed that assert is, like in other languages, only reproduced when on __debug__ so ig you find an error on runtime, would it assert it as well?

Comment: This is not very pythonic, and it is mentioned before if you run Python interpreter without debut option the asserts are ignored...
P.D: -O     : optimize generated bytecode slightly; also PYTHONOPTIMIZE=x

Comment: what happens when self.value = 0. 
If I run >>> assert 0, it raises an error. 
I suppose you will have to alter your example.
**edited question**

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to raise inside of a ternary, the trick is to use `exec`:

```py
def raising_ternary(x):
    return x if x else exec("raise Exception('its just not true')")
```

As you can see calling it with `True` will do the first part of the ternary and calling it with `False` will raise the exception:

```
>>> def raising_ternary(x):
...     return x if x else exec("raise Exception('its just not true')")
... 
>>> raising_ternary(True)
True
>>> raising_ternary(False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in raising_ternary
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: its just not true
>>>
```

Comment: while I think this was genius, from a Pythonic point of view it also makes my eyes bleed.....

Comment: haha i knew the stigma that comes with this type of suggestion but i couldnt resist at least posting it for other people to see :D

Comment: `exec()` is dangerous and shouldn't be used this way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could test for the bool separately:

```
if expr: raise exception('foo')
return val
```

That way, you could test for `expr` earlier.