# invalid syntax with ternary operator after import within a single line script

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-operator

I'm running some python as a single-line script, but getting the following error

```
>>> import ipaddress; (ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.1.1.1') in ipaddress.IPv4Network('1.1.1.1/32')) ? raise Exception('xxx') : pass;
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import ipaddress; (ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.1.1.1') in ipaddress.IPv4Network('1.1.1.1/32')) ? raise Exception('xxx') : pass;
                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've also tried:

```
>>> import ipaddress; raise Exception('xxx') if (ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.1.1.1') in ipaddress.IPv4Network('1.1.1.1/32'));
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import ipaddress; raise Exception('xxx') if (ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.1.1.1') in ipaddress.IPv4Network('1.1.1.1/32'));
                                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this invalid syntax? Is there an alternative way that I can achieve the same end goal?

I'm running this code from a third party tool (terraform) so it has to be a single-line script.

Comment: Conditional expressions are for expressions, not statements. They are not a replacement for `if` statements.

Comment: You want to raise an exception when the IP is in the range?

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't have a ternary operator with `?` as such

Equivalent:

```
condition_if_true if condition else condition_if_false
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax here for ternary operations in Python is

```
a if condition else b
```

but note that `b` here is an expression, not an arbitrary Python statement. You can't use `raise` or `pass` in a conditional expression.

If you want to raise an exception when the condition is false, the shortest you can get your code is:

```
import ipaddress
if not ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.1.1.1') in ipaddress.IPv4Network('1.1.1.1/32'): raise Exception('xxx')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t raise an exception with the ternary operator, since it deals with expressions, and `raise` is a statement. This seems like it would work, but also raises a syntax error.

```
import ipaddress; if ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.1.1.1') in ipaddress.IPv4Network('1.1.1.1/32'): raise Exception('xxx')
```

So the closest you can get is probably this (which @glhr [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55771520/3830997)):

```
import ipaddress
if ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.1.1.1') in ipaddress.IPv4Network('1.1.1.1/32'): raise Exception('xxx')
```

or this (which also shows the correct syntax for Python's ternary operator):

```
def raise_error(err):
    raise err

import ipaddress; raise_error(Exception('xxx')) if ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.1.1.1') in ipaddress.IPv4Network('1.1.1.1/32') else None
```

You may also find some useful ideas here (turns out they also thought of my second idea): [raise statement on a conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295841/raise-statement-on-a-conditional-expression)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to achieve this.

```
import ipaddress
try:
    ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.1.1.1') in ipaddress.IPv4Network('1.1.1.1/32')
except:
    raise Exception('xxx')
```

It's one liner will be for throwing exception will be

```
if ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.1.1.1') in ipaddress.IPv4Network('1.1.1.1/32'): raise Exception('xxx')
```

Comment: I need the one-liner to throw an exception if the condition is false

Comment: Updated, please check

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you @ChrisSnow :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad way of doing it. But everything is on one line. You are importing the module every time you need to use.

```py
if not __import__("ipaddress").IPv4Address('1.1.1.1') in __import__("ipaddress").IPv4Network('1.1.1.1/32'): raise Exception('xxx')
```