# Why does this code raise TypeError : exceptions must derive from BaseException?

Tags: python, exception, conditional-operator

```py
if False:
    raise Exception
else:
   print('else')
```

The code above works fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8ywS.png)

```py
raise Exception if False else print('else')
```

I don't know why this code raise TypeError : exception must derive from BaseException.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHXEC.png)

While studying exceptions, I wanted to write more concise code, but exceptions in ternary operators did not work normally. I expected the code above and the code below to give the same result.

Comment: "I wanted to write more concise code" well, those two pieces of code do different things. This is interpreted as `raise (Exception if False else print('else'))` so in the case it goes to the `else`, you `raise None` because `print("else")` returns `None`. Hence the error. Just write an if-else statement. lines are pretty much free

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10295905/1407202):

> Inline/ternary if is an expression, not a statement. Your attempt
> means "if bool, return value, else return the result of raise
> expression" - which is nonsense of course, because raise exception is
> itself a statement not an expression.

If you really want to achieve this, you can do the following as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10296112/1407202):

```
def raiser(ex): raise ex

raiser(Exception) if False else print("else")
```